# What to do with a question where answers form a conversation?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, old-questions, quality-improvement

From [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18364):

> Incidentally, you may notice a practice in some older questions where answers form a sort of conversation between the person asking the original question and those responding. These generally date back to the early beta period before the comment feature was introduced - it should be avoided now.

I just came across such a question

- [What do you do when you can't use ViewState?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45176/11682469)

Here's the conversation

1. User posts an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45368/11682469)

   > I have always recreated my dynamic controls in the LoadViewState event. You can store the number of controls needed to be created in the viewstate and then dynamically create that many of them using the LoadControl method inside the LoadViewState event. In this event you have access to the ViewState but it has not been restored to the controls on the page yet.
2. OP responds in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45919/11682469) (curiously, the user added a comment to that answer days later)

   > If I dynamically bind the controls there, will ASP.NET automatically handle their state? The problem with doing it in Page_Load is that viewstate is already loaded and it does not add the dynamic controls in the repeater. I would think it would do the same in LoadViewState?
3. User responds to the answer in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46227/11682469)

   > Yes, the runtime will populate the viewstate of the controls as long as you create the right number of them. The controls' viewstate will populate after this event.
4. OP replies in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46259/11682469) (citing the previous answer)

   > In what order is LoadViewState called? I added an overridden method signature and it does not seem to be stepping into it.

These two answers, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46259/11682469) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46306/11682469), also look like they might rather be asking for clarification. But I don't know enough about the topic to be sure.

It seems to me that multiple actions are necessary to clean it up, and the tools at my disposal (flags, suggested edits) are not sufficient.

Possibly, #3 could be added to #1 ("The runtime will populate the viewstate of the controls as long as you create the right number of them. The controls' viewstate will populate after this event."). #2 would then no longer be needed and #4 could be turned into a comment to #1. The user's later [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176/what-do-you-do-when-you-cant-use-viewstate#comment954_45919) could also be added to #1, maybe as an "Edit:" to show it's a response to the OP's comment.

**What to do with a question so old there weren't comments yet and answers form a conversation?**

Comment: I mean, you could go through the trouble of editing and all that, but since your edits would go into the review queue, I wouldn't suggest it as I think it would be hard to explain in the edit summary what you are attempting. I'd suggest just leaving it as is. No one should be using Web Forms these days anyway ;-).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, that's exactly why I do not consider suggested edits a useful tool for such a complicated case. I fear they would all get rejected.

Comment: Definitely a good question (got my vote). I'm afraid the answer's going to be "leave 'em alone" though...

Comment: So... within the span of four days comments were added? In the "If I dynamically ..." non-answer, there's a comment by the person who answered the question.

Comment: @JL2210 I was baffled, too. I don't know when exactly comments were introduced but based on this question, I believe it may have been early September 2008. The comment there may be one of the first ever. The first [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/19756/1) I found is from late September 2008.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion, you should either

1. leave them alone (not a ton of harm being caused here that I can tell), or
2. flag for moderator attention, explaining the situation (or just link to this Meta Q). A moderator can then convert any of the relevant answers to comments, should they deem it necessary.

   Though AFAIK such comments would appear under the question rather than under a specific answer; I'm not sure if mods have the ability to send an answer to live as a comment under another answer (it'd be a good feature...)

Comment: I think they can send an answer and all its comments to another answer but it needs trickery that Shog9 explained in a chatroom and the mods present all went silent so I assume they need to ask him again if they are going to use it.

Comment: Not so much trickery as "tedious pain in the rear"

Comment: @Shog9 so *that* is why all the mods where silent. I see.

Comment: Mod on another SE site here.. a mod just need to input the post ID as the target post for comment conversion, so yes, it's already possible to convertan answer to comment on another answer in the same Q&A thread...